# Can the Samsung TV SDK 4.1 target the 7000-9000 series of Smart TVs?

Tags: sdk, samsung-smart-tv

Has anyone had experience with game development for Samsung Smart TVs and knows if the Samsung SDK 4.1 available for the series of 7000-9000 Samsung Smart TVs?

Comment: Questions asking for lists of software or similar recommendations aren't generally considered constructive here. What is it you're actually looking for? To me it reads like you really want to know if SDK 4.1 is available for a particular series range of TVs (7000 to 9000). That is a far more answerable question...

Comment: You're definitely right, I've updated the question.

Comment: We don't get a lot of Smart TV questions here. I'm not sure what kind of response you'll get but you're likely to get a better one at the Samsung forums for their Smart TVs: http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/index

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkReleaseNote), it says that sdk 4.1 supports 2013. The only sdk that says that it supports to 2010 models(7000-9000) is sdk 1.510.

Comment: year of release is coded by letter, not series number, 2010 is C****, 7000-9000 series are present in all release years 2010-2013 (C7000 - E7000)

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung website](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/legacy/overview.html) says:

> The latest version of the Samsung Smart TV SDK includes Emulators of all platforms:

> SDK Emulator 1.5 - for 2010 platform
> SDK Emulator 2.5 - for 2011 platform
> SDK Emulator 3.5 - for 2012 platform
> SDK Emulator 4.5 - for 2013 platform
> SDK Emulator 5.1 Beta - for 2014 platform

Debug:

> Using JS Debugger: 2010 and 2011 Emulators

Upload to TV:

> Copying the application to an USB memory and running it on TV. This
> method works only on 2012 platform and is not recommended.

There's no mention of testing process for c7000 TVs released in 2010. Based on release history of legacy platforms, you may develop for 2010 models with SDK 4.1, even with 5.1

[Download](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/legacy/tools/history.html) for Samsung old legacy TV SDK.